# onPlay (or onClick?) Trigger Full Screen Video on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, html, ipad, html5-video

Using the following HTML and JavaScript, I've been trying to trigger fullscreen video on the iPad. This works if there is only one video, but because there are numerous videos on the same page, only the first one works. I don't know how to separate out the videos so that they will all work properly. I've tried changing the IDs, and still, it doesn't work. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

HTML:

```
<video id="test1" width="100%" height="200px" poster="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/example.png">
<source src="http://video.example.com/example.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<button id="test2">Play Video</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var video = document.getElementById('test1'),
    play = document.getElementById('test2'),
    time;
video.addEventListener('webkitbeginfullscreen', function() {
    play.innerText = 'Play Video';
    window.clearInterval(time);
});
video.addEventListener('webkitendfullscreen', function() {
    video.pause();
});
play.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    time = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            video.webkitEnterFullscreen();
        }
        catch(e) {}
    }, 250);
    play.innerText = 'loading ...';
    video.play();   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking at the page that contains multiple videos, it's hard to know for sure. But it sounds like you may be using the #test1 and #test2 IDs in your HTML more than once, in which case `document.getElementById('test1')` would only return the first matching element on the page. Check out the result of what's being console'd out here: http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/q7Pyh/

Try using document.getElementsByTagName or document.getElementsByClassName and looping through the results to add your event listeners to each video on the page. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/tjnicolaides/NDYkU/

```
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video'),
    play_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('play_button'),
    time;

for(var i=0; i< videos.length; i++) {
    // add event listeners and stuff here
}

for(var i=0; i < play_buttons.length; i++) {
    // add event listeners and stuff here
}
```